# String from CSV into array (Java)

Tags: java

I am trying to put column values (CSV file) into an array.

The CSV file:

[image]

My code:

```
    public void readFile1()
    {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        
        // use comma as separator
        String[] passengerDetails = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
   
      
        bookingDetails pd = new bookingDetails(passengerDetails[0], passengerDetails[1], passengerDetails[2], passengerDetails[3]);
        String x = passengerDetails[2];
        System.out.println(passengerDetails[2]); // how to put these values inside an array
       
    

    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

The output of my code:

[image]

Comment: em, you already store them in an array, only that you override the values in each iteration

Comment: But when I use .length() I get the length for each line.
I want to be able to access each cell.

Comment: I don't understand the question, to be honest. Which length you need?

Comment: So, you need to store all names inside an unique array?

Comment: If you need an array of the passenger names you just have to use a counter in the while loop and use `passengerNames[counter]=passengerDetails[2];` and `counter++;`, you may also want to skip the first entry or to use an ArrayList if you don't know the size in advance. Otherwise please ty to clarify your question.

Comment: Maybe my question is:
How to access each cell in the CSV file.